# How to create Android App by using VueJs SPA (created in Laravel)?

Tags: vue.js, laravel-8, vue-native

I am using VueJS in Laravel for Frontend Development and its working properly. Can I use the same VujeJs frontend code to create Android App. If yes then what will be the steps?

I do not know how to use Native in Laravel VueJS SPA to create Android App

Answer (score 0):

Simplest way would be to migrate your app towards Nuxt and use the following Ionic module: https://github.com/nuxt-modules/ionic

That way, you'll be able to get SSG/SSR and also deploy it on Android thanks to the Webview wrapping thanks to Ionic.

Laravel is not really part of the plan tho. You probably need to check if you can extract the Vue part or see how to use Ionic with Laravel.